# How to keep Vagrant box running in background?

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

Instead of running a vagrant box in the background (via vagrant ssh in a terminal shell), is there a way to run it using a daemon? This could be used for having people connect to your box (via vagrant connect).

Right now I'm just having a terminal window stay on vagrant share --ssh.

I can't do

vagrant share --ssh &

because it requires my password and I couldn't put in my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, whenever you start a Vagrant box with `vagrant up`, it will already be running in the background (in VirtualBox or VMWare, for example). You don't need to worry about keeping an ssh session connected to it.

Comment: I'm not using virtual box and vmware, just using vagrant up;vagrant ssh. And that's it.

Comment: Right, but vagrant is just a wrapper around a virtual machine provider, the most common ones being VirtualBox or VMware. (More info here on the docs page: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/providers.html.)